# ColdFusion Memory Leak when Calling Java + JNA

Tags: java, c++, dll, memory-leaks, coldfusion

ColdFusion dies(with memory leak or something) on the second attempt to utilize a Java Class. The Java class is wrapper for the [wkToHtmltoPDf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) dll. It uses the JNA Native library to interface with the dll compiled from c++; So the execution trace would look something like this:

ColdFusion --> Java --> JNA --> wkToHtmltox.dll(c++)

Everything works fine on the first run. However, the ColdFusion server crashes if I try and access the page again. I have to manually restart the ColdFusion server to bring it up again. Also, the server just dies without giving any kind of error in the logs. Window event logs indicates the faulting module is C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll. At first I was sure it was a going to be a problem with how JNA interacts with the dll or some bug in the DLL itself. But the funny thing is that I can get it to work by having ColdFusion cold load the library.

My coldfusion file looks like this:

```
var pdf =CreateObject("java", "pdf");
pdf.open("http://www.google.com","c:\test.pdf");
pdf.setOrientation("Landscape");
pdf.convert();
pdf = JavaCast( "null", 0 );
```

The pdf is a java class registered with ColdFusion using the Application.cfc [javaSettings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffd.html). As mentioned above, the pdf class is just a wrapper for the dll. As is above, the cfml will crash the second time it runs. However, if I were to comment out lines 2-4, run it once and then uncomment those lines then it will work just fine the second, third and forth time I run it. At this point no matter how many times the cfml is run it will not crash. This works up until the coldfusion server is restarted. Then it will revert back to working for the first run, crashing on the second.

Riddle me that oh Riddler?

Now I say memory leak. But it only spikes from 800mb to 1400mb on the second attempt. I have given it 2gb to work with and it never utilizes all of it. There is no spike in CPU usage. It just dies. If I comment out the last line then it may take 10 seconds to die. If I leave it in then it will generally die instantaneously.

You can see my Java code here: ideone.com/mJjOBT

Microsoft Event Info:pastebin.com/sWHz7SaX

Comment: Nothing is being written to your ColdFusion exception.log?

Comment: Can you share your Windows event log showing the error?

Comment: You can find it on pastebin here: http://www.pastebin.ca/2909863

Comment: I'm learning towards a scoping issue - had a similar problem to this where CF would run out of memory over time. But your example looks much more aggressive and easier to replicate. Maybe try doing a heap dump and analysing that to see what objects are being created and/or duplicated - that would back your theory of a memory leak.

Check out this blog post, it's bit of a read but well worth it: http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/07/16/finding-memory-leaks-coldfusion-jvm

Comment: Do not know if it is related to the problem, but given that you are creating a new instance of the class each time, the use of `public` variables (and the whole `init` scheme) seems .. odd, and could be problematic thread wise. Any specific reason for it?